# Servo interfering with 433MHz RF

Tags: arduino, rf, servo, atmega328p, 433mhz

I'm using an Atmega328P running at 16Mhz (similar to an Arduino UNO). to control a 433Mhz Superheterodyne RF receiver ([WL101-541](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/433mhz-rf-Transmitter-and-Receiver-superheterodyne-UHF-ASK-remote-control-Module-with-Antenna-Kit-small-size/32651427149.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.1.1h3VXe&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_4_10152_10065_10151_10344_10068_10130_10345_10324_10342_10547_10325_10343_10546_10340_10341_10548_5690020_10545_10541_10562_10084_10083_10307_10539_5080015_10312_10059_10313_10314_10534_10533_100031_10604_10603_10103_10594_10557_10558_10596_10595_10142_10107,searchweb201603_12,ppcSwitch_5&algo_expid=264f1ece-c2f3-40fd-9d5b-9c09147c7c12-0&algo_pvid=264f1ece-c2f3-40fd-9d5b-9c09147c7c12&rmStoreLevelAB=3)) and two [TowerPro SG90](http://www.towerpro.com.tw/product/sg90-analog/) analog servos.

Everything is working except for the situation I describe here.  In the event a servo is under a load, such that it is remaining active trying to hold position, RF cannot be received.  I believe that the motor activity is causing some sort of interference.  I have been unable to track it down or work around it and am looking for ideas.

Some details:

1. A single switching power regulator capable of 3A (far more than is
   being used).
2. Power and ground split at the power regulator with one 
   path going to and from the servos, and another going to and from the
   MCU and RF receiver.  My understanding is that this will minimize
   any ground loops.
3. The servos currently reside behind 3 220uF capacitors to handle startup current needs (There are 3 because I had no larger ones available).
4. I have tried a variety of other capacitors across the    serve power and ground to try to filter any feedback to no effect.
5. I    have tried twisting the servo cable.  This had no effect.
6. I have    tried placing Ferrite around
   the servo cable (both straight through    and 3 loops).  This had no
   effect.

I'm not sure how to proceed identifying the issue or fixing it.  Thanks.

**Update: 1/23/18:**

Running with the theme that it is likely the power, here are some additional findings.

1. The issue does not occur when powering with 5V from my Tekpower
   TP3005T variable linear power supply.
2. Issue does occur when powering
   with a L7805CV Voltage Regulator to supply the 5V
   with 10uF capacitors on both the input and output lines.
3. Issue does occur when powering using an [LM2596 based buck converter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01GJ0SC2C).
4. I need to confirm this again, but I believe the issue occurs using the L7805CV and LM2596 whether they are powered using a battery or the Tekpower.
5. Using two L7805CV regulators, one to the receiver and another to the servos, from the same power source appears to greatly reduce, if not resolve the issue.

Comment: `RF cannot be received` ... how do you know?

Comment: @jsotola I guess "cannot be received" is a little vague.  I have an LED that flashes, but I also have a serial hook up.  I'm not getting any valid reconstructed messages from the software library.  I'm not sure what the antenna is actually "seeing".

Comment: To be blunt, you have an unsuitable power source and an unsuitable radio.  If you want something that actually works, use batteries and an 2.4 GHz FSK chip like the nRF24, or else use a traditional narrowband FM/PPM set - but finding one will be far trickier than going to 2.4 GHz.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I don't believe the power source is related to the issue, problem persists with either a battery or desktop supply.  RF receiver voltage seems to have minimal fluctuation due to motor activity.

Comment: Normal debugging to determine if conducted or radiated interference is by isolation.  Can you measure Conducted ripple with AC coupled 50 Ohm load?  Do you have Rx Ripple specs? Does Rx share Servo DC power wires from power source? ( bad ) Servo motors impedance ? 5~25 Ohms??,  Cap g.p. or ultralow ESR?

Comment: @denver even much better 433 MHz receivers than you have are very susceptible to switching power supply noise.  Add in a loaded servo and it only gets worse.  In comparison, the radio you want to use is truly horrible - the 2.4 GHz chips are both better radios, use better modulation, operate at frequencies where more locally generated self interference has rolled off, and are less expensive, too.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I can't answer most of your questions, we are pushing my experience limit.  I don't believe I have a way to measure ripple.  Power and ground forks at power source, one fork going to servos, one to RF.  Specs on the Rx and Servo are brief, no ripple or impedance stated.  Currently using electrolytic caps, but I have tried ceramic caps as well.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I was originally using a linear power regulator.  It had the same problem.  Can't switch to 2.4Ghz need 433MHz for compatibility.  Range is not an issue, just the motor interference ... wherever it is coming from ...

Comment: You can go crazy with ferrite beads on all low current signals and RF chokes on supplies and it will likely make a difference, but realize you are choosing to do things the hard way.

Comment: Cant you test with separate power sources?

Comment: @denver -- I build a consumer product using a similar IC.  I suspect I may even know the Asian company building that IC.  I wouldn't listen to all this chatter about needing a new radio.  The goal isn't to toss your design, right?  Do you have a spectrum analyzer?  Can you see the demodulated signal coming out of the IC, when the system goes haywire?  Go to Amazon and buy some different power source board (I have some little cheapo LDO regulator boards), try it with some batteries?  As Tony is saying, it sounds like power.  Tony is a good EE, he has helped me many times.

Comment: @Tony -- and yes, sometimes I wish you could help me more in layman's terms for us non EE's. ;)

Comment: I noticed on a cheap receiver IC, using a power adapter through a cheap LDO (notice a trend...?), I might see some really wonky demodulated signals.  You can have the amplifier in the Receiver IC backfeeding all kinds of garbage, that's monkeying with the received signal.  Sorry not a great EE answer, but my vote is power too.  When I say check the demodulated signal, like where does the signal from the receiver go to your microcontroller?  Check that line with an oscilloscope when you spin up the servo.  What is going on, how does that signal look compared to normal operation?

Comment: Try these boards from Amazon. I use these to prototype stuff. Seem okay: https://www.amazon.com/UCEC-Breadboard-Supply-Arduino-Solderless/dp/B01ELAGIO6/

Comment: Some radio transmit/receive pairs offer two modulation methods: on-off keying and FM. You might be better off with FM. Troubleshooting noise on that receiver likely requires knowing which chip it uses (could be very difficult to find).

Comment: @Leroy105 Thanks for the suggestions.  I have updated the question with recent test findings.  Unfortunately I do not have a spectrum analyzer.  I can but on Oscilloscope on the line, but mine is on loan until next week.  If the issue persists I will hook it up at that time and let you know what I see.  I have one of those breadboard supplies, I'll try it out, but I expect it to behave similar to the L7805CV I tested on.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Two supplies does work around the issue, won't work for a long term solution for me.  Any suggestion on any sort of decoupling that can be applied to a one supply solution?  Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be running a servo through an everyday linear regulator anyway, and *especially* not the same one powering this primitive radio.

Comment: @glen_geek I'm not aware of an option to change the modulation method on the modules I am using.

Comment: It is easy to add an RC filter for the Radio for < 0.1V drop as LPF.  This was a test to see if conducted noise isolated from 2 supplies solves the problem .

Comment: The servo should be on its own voltage regulator so that heavy loads don't sag your MCU and RX supplies. the servo regulator should be set so it limits at some controlled current that is lower than current limit on your main supply. If the servo stalls and overloads the regulator, then it will collapse its own voltage regulator and not the main supply, MCU or RX voltages.

Comment: Tony's on point here with that filter.   I can speak to the fact that if I hook up some wonky power sources, I have seen oddball stuff on a receiver like that before.  In non-EE, when that servo spins it creates all kind of noise and oddities in the power line across the whole that can monkey with your receiver IC. At the end of the day your receiver IC is this oscillator, and wants good and clean power otherwise the oscillator doesn't oscilliate at the right frequency and your receiver stops working (in the IC..).  When you probe the IC data output with the servo, you'll see what I'm saying..

Comment: @VincePatron How do you go about current limiting a basic regulator?

Comment: On a basic regulator, it's built in. LM7805 it's a bit over 1 Amp. On fancier regulators, it's typically set with a current sense resistor and and/or a bias setting resistor. Everyone here is freaking over the RF noise, but I would definitely look at supply voltage problem because you mention it happens when the servo is loaded. Put a scope probe on your voltage rail and see if that's bouncing around when the servo is loaded. Apply some force on the servo arm and see if supply voltage bounces. The more pressure you apply, the more current needs to hold the servo arm position.

Comment: @Vince - This is not crazy advice either.   Good call.

Comment: FYI SG90 draws up to 0.75A with nasty spikes, even without a load:-  http://www.bhabbott.net.nz/Servo/HXT-900.jpg

Comment: What makes you think that radio is actually tested and legal to use anywhere in the world? From the picture alone, the radio module in itself looks like an EMC nightmare. And then on top of that, you hook up the cheap crap radio to cheap crap electromechanics... sorry, but this is as far from professional engineering as it gets.

Comment: I know a $400MM private-equity behemoth of a company that uses this companies ICs for radio products. I was just looking at the datasheet pinout from Alibaba.  This is the fancy receiver with an RSSI out!  Maybe the module may or may not pass EMC, but that's a layout issue. But that has nothing to do with the noise issue.  Everyone dogs on these components, but lots of large companies use these types of parts.... I think the issue is lots of USA engineers aren't comfortable due to language and culture barriers to source these parts. So they dog on them, and just go to Digi and pay 100% more.

Comment: @Leroy105 It is _not_ just the layout, it is the radio characteristics. What's the bandwidth characteristics? Out of band emissions? Sensitivity and blocking characteristics? Adjacent channel rejection? They just say "it is good". Also, it is using ASK or OOK, so it will get constantly crapped on by every other device on the band. I know large companies who use similar parts and as a result their radio is _crap_. Example: cars from many manufacturers can't be locked/unlocked if there's other any other (legal) radio anywhere on the 434MHz band.

Comment: @Lundin Getting a little off topic.  There is nothing illegal about the receiver/transmitter use in the US.  This is a hobby/learning project so I'm not concerned with passing any EMC testing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9mdPs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks.  I'll do some testing and report back.  Does the filter need to be applied directly in front of the receiver, or can it cover the MCU as well (the whole non-servo power branch)?  Is this a lowpass filter with a cut-off frequency around 1575Hz?  I used the equation 1/(2*pi*R*C).  Was this value picked based on experience with some expected noise values from the servos?

Comment: HE uses 10 ohms as a starting point. 10mA to receiver and 1 ohms causes 0.1 volt drop, which is within normal tolerances for supply voltages. You can also use 100uF in place of 10uF, if Receiver problems still occur.

Comment: I'd use a ferrite bead or an inductor instead of the resistor.

Comment: And you want a ferrite on the signal line to the servo, too.

Comment: @analogsystemrf  If you had a noise issue like this from a servo, could you use a spectrum analyzer (think coax with exposed tip) to probe the traces and look for the frequency of the noise, and than build the filter as needed based on that frequency you see?  I've never had an issue like this on an RF board.

Comment: Any DC power noise test should be done with a 50 coax terminated with an AC coupled 50 load load.  This can be a scope or a spectrum analyzer.  Since the PS source needs to be << 1 Ohm in most cases, 50 Ohm suppresses stray false readings from long probe ground leads and cable resonances. So the 10:1 probe with clips removed for exposed tip + ring to short test pins <1cm is also acceptable up to 100 or 200 Mhz

Comment: But he clearly has a functional  issue and the servo pulse rate can lead to current noise right inside the 100KHz IF bandwidth.

Comment: Filter worked.  I used a 10Ohm resistor, C1 was a 100uF electrolytic capacitor, and C2 was a 100nF ceramic capacitor.  Using a smaller 10uF at C1 worked about 70% of the time.

Answer (score 3):

In working on the issue I came about 3 solutions.  Each solution by itself resolved the issue - but a combo is probably the correct approach.  I decided to post them here in case they can help anyone else.

1. Apply a lowpass filter in the power/ground lines to the reciever as suggested by Tony in the accepted answer.  Using 10uF for C1 did not quite filter enough, I had to use 100 uF.  This results in a drop-off frequency of around 160 Hz.
2. In my design the regulator output was forked with one 5V/Gnd going to the servos and another to the MCU & receiver.  I was using a LM2596 based buck converter.  Taking the ground from the servos and attaching it on the input side of the regulator also resolved the issue.
3. Using TowerPro SG92R instead of the SG90.  The SG92R is a revision of the SG90. The servos are nearly identical, with the same form factor, however the SG92R has a higher torque. The higher torque reduced the amount of activity to hold the position under load. This reduced the interference to the point it was no longer a problem.

Comment: Check out the USB spectrum analyzers on Ebay for $80.  I use a Rigol ($1500-ouch), but the USB ones  (software based) actually do work... I've measured them using a signal generator vs. my Rigol.  You'll bring your RF game to the next level. ;)

Comment: @Leroy105 I wasn't aware of those.  Thanks for pointing them out.

Answer (score 1):

Tony called out measuring the power ripple going to the RX receiver.

I didn't want to bury this in the comments. I spent some time looking at the actual nuts and bolts of making that power ripple measurement.

This [describes how to make that measurement](https://www.edn.com/Home/PrintView?contentItemId=4433242) using an oscilloscope.

This [shows how to create the 50 ohm coax cable for this measurement](http://www.rantec.com/application/LVAN_HDMA100.pdf)

Here are some [some engineers describing how they create their test cable](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/292558/measuring-noise-on-dc-rails-with-active-probe)

The importance of keeping the measurement at 50 ohms, is a bit outside my depth.  Other than to say, pretty much everything engineering wise uses 50 ohm impedances.  (75 ohms, is used for certain things too, but 50 ohms is what I mostly see for PCB projects).

Your scope inputs, expect a 50 ohm impedance signal.  So you need to keep the measurement at 50 ohms otherwise the measurement is not accurate.

(Certain efficiency stuff with 50 ohm impedance and AC signals.  Impedance calculation start to get into some heavier math...).

The nuts and bolts is that you can make this measurement using a 50 ohm coax cable, but it must be "terminated" on one end to keep the impedance at 50 ohms.

We are talking strip a 50 ohm coax cable at one end, and have the bare center conductor exposed as your new oscilloscope probe.

The articles says you can use a 50 ohm resistor in series on this exposed tip, or you can just use a 50 ohm coax cable that already has the 50 ohm termination on it.  (I would just buy a 50 ohm coax cable, with two BNC connectors, and cut one off, strip the coax, and solder on that DC blocking cap.  You can use the DC blocking cap as your new probe tip.  Or if you have a scope with AC coupling, you can just that.  The important part is keeping your cable at 50 ohms!)

You would want to block off the DC component of the power signal, so you can put a capacitor in series with your coax cable (I saw a X7R, 0.6 uF recommended for this on the web).  Or you can buy that fancy $500 DC blocker thing.  I'll go with the cap in series.

So, if you weren't using a mystery IC there might be a published ripple value. In your case, probably not.  But here you go on the nuts and bolts of making measurement.

Comment: While it might see low frequencies disturbing the operation of the circuit, a scope is the wrong instrument for measuring the more challenging issue of radio frequency interference conducted down or radiating from power and signal lines.  Professionally a spectrum analyzer would be used (either with a coupling probe, pickup antenna or a very solid DC block), but a halfway decent 433 MHz receiver would also work for detecting components in the band related to the observed problem.

Comment: Just nuts and bolts again: a "coupling probe", could be a 50 ohm coax cable with that stripped and exposed center conductor again in this case you are using the spectrum analyzer.  Just hover that cable 1mm above the traces, and go around the board using the tip as your "probe". So the general approach is what sort of noise do I see on the spectrum analyzer before I activate the servo and the receiver is working? When you activate the servo, what sort of new noise do you see?  Eliminate the new noise = problem solved.  This is kind of a down and dirty way to get the job done.

Comment: @Leroy105 Thanks for all the additional details.  I'll update the post after I absorb all this and do some testing.  It will likely be a few days.

Comment: @Leroy105 Issue is solved, so just playing around some now.  I don't have setup as recommended so not sure how much that affects what I am seeing.  I have a DYI scope with a built in 1MOhm/20pF.  I put my DYI scope on the power line before the receiver and the signal is pretty consistent regardless of what the servos are doing (the servos do seem to cause a very minor phase shift).  When I put the probe on the ground line however I do see jitter of about .2V when the servos are active.

Comment: What is interesting is if I put the probe on the signal line from the receiver I get what looks like noise (expected), but when the servo is running I get a nice square wave (which I suppose is some of my interference).  Anyway, thanks for the help.  A lot more to learn :)

Comment: @denver -- yeah, I'm not an expert interfacing with servos.  I wouldn't know exactly what to expect.  My guess would be that the square wave is noise from the servo.   I just know those RX ICs are very sensitive to noise and clean power.  I've seen it.